# htaccess trialing slash issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

We have a static PhP website that is getting a 404 error when we have a trailing slash.  We would like the website to re-direct `www.example.com/our-company/` to `wwww.example.com/our-company`

Currently the `www.example.com/our-company/` is NOT working.  Below is our currently htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After doing more research we were able to find the solution:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```